# How to move or create a window on the right side on Vimscript?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to modify project.vim to open the project window on the right side instead of in the left. I see several references in the source to "vertical new", "vertical split" and "vertical resize". Trying them I see that a new vertical split is opened to the left, but I can't find how can I make a new vertical split open (or move) to the right side. I know the command Control-W + r will move the window to the right, but I don't know how this is done using vimscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing `vertical new` to `rightbelow vertical new`.

Also, see `:help vertical` and all the friends listed just after it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also `set splitright` so that vertically split windows are always created on the right hand side.

**Update:**

It seems the plugin is coded quite inflexibly, so you'll need to take one of two approaches:

**1)** Change this line in the plugin's source code

```
let b:proj_locate_command='silent! wincmd H'
```

to

```
let b:proj_locate_command='silent! wincmd L'
```

or **2)** For whichever mappings you use to open the project window, append `<C-W>L` or `:wincmd L` to the end of the mappings.

You should also email the author and ask for him/her to provide a way to configure this behaviour more easily.

Comment: For some reason, it works for my windows but not for project.vim windows. Also, I don't want all windows to be on the right - for example the NERD_tree or taglist windows.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should consider using `wincmd r` after doing a vertical split. <kbd><C-w>*c*</kbd> and `wincmd c` most of time are equivalent.